# Error display when trying to copy columns to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a range of columns into a new workbook with the following code:

```
Sub Rlaunch()
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Worksheets("CAPEX").Range("A:F")
    r1.Copy
    
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    
    With wbNew
    Set r2 = Range("A1")
    r2.PasteSpecial.xlPasteValues
    End With
    
End Sub
```

The code is working however I find two problems:

1. It pastes the columns where I want however I get the "Run-time error '424': Object required" on the follow line of code:

```
r2.PasteSpecial.xlPasteValues
```

2. Also, the code is still copying formulas from the source book that I don't want to be copied in the new workbook (they are in column E) even though I'm using xlPasteValues.

How do I solve these two issues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define the sheet if you want to paste to a new workbook. It's also recommended to only move the non empty cells.
This alternative version using an array will do what you want and much faster:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub copyRng()
        Dim arr, wbNew As Workbook, wsNew, lastrow As Long
        lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in column A
        arr = Sheet1.Range("A1:F" & lastrow).Value2
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1)
        With wsNew
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))) = arr
        End With
    End Sub
```